# Convert XML to Json. And get specific data (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml

everyone! I`ve completely stuck with one project.
https://plnkr.co/edit/lcPGvAE10qhY9Px89c1e?p=preview
I need to convert xml to json(that seems to work). But when i save it from plnkr can`t open it offline.
Would be greatful if you help me get specific data from this json.
1) Spouse for each person
2) Last 10 persons.
3) ancestors for specific person.
Thank you for your answers. Have a nice day

Comment: It looks like there is one ancestor ("person"). Are you looking for spouse for each descendant?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ryan. You can check xml tree file to see the dependences. Overall structure is something like: person A - marriage - person B - children - person C - marriage - person D - children - person E. So for person E we will have ancestors  A,B,C,D. Spauses as written above A-B, C-D

Comment: Here is a graphical xml tree to better understand the structure. https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj9u5jLk93mAhXc6eAKHeoWDaEQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.as-pushkin.ru%2Findex.php%3Fcnt%3D4&psig=AOvVaw2mYDFu8hpGh4WfZe-TmOUN&ust=1577787750993770

Comment: There is no cases in this tree where persons have more than 1 wife/husband(i mean married-divoursed-married). I need no complex functions. It would be great if i can display any person from this json

Comment: Have you explored Defiant? https://www.defiantjs.com/

Comment: I have xml => json. And json as string. I dont know how to display random person from this json

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tried to find out any specific person using his/her name from this data set. I know this is not the answer but i think this will at least give you some idea about the path of the solution.
Here is [JS-bin link](https://jsbin.com/civagomofo/edit?js,console)

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`{"person":{"name":"Abram","surname":"Hannibal","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1696","dateofdeath":"1781","childreninfo":"","family":"","marriage":{"person":{"name":"Hristina-Regina","surname":"Von Shenberg","maidenname":"Unknown","dateofbirth":"Unknown","dateofdeath":"1705","childreninfo":"","family":""}},"children":{"person":{"name":"Osip","surname":"Hannibal","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1744","dateofdeath":"1807","childreninfo":"","family":"","marriage":{"person":{"name":"Maria","surname":"Pushkina","maidenname":"Hannibal","dateofbirth":"1745","dateofdeath":"1819","childreninfo":"","family":"","children":{"person":{"name":"Nadezhda","surname":"Pushkina","maidenname":"Hannibal","dateofbirth":"1775","dateofdeath":"1836","childreninfo":"","family":"","marriage":{"person":{"name":"Sergei","surname":"Pushkin","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1770","dateofdeath":"1838","childreninfo":"","family":""}},"children":{"person":{"name":"Lev","surname":"Pushkin","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1805","dateofdeath":"1852","childreninfo":"","family":"","marriage":{"person":{"name":"Olga","surname":"Pushkina","maidenname":"Pavlistsheva","dateofbirth":"1797","dateofdeath":"1868","childreninfo":"","family":""}},"children":{"person":{"name":"Alexandr","surname":"Pushkin","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1799","dateofdeath":"1837","childreninfo":"","family":"","marriage":{"person":{"name":"Natalia","surname":"Pushkina","maidenname":"Goncharova","dateofbirth":"1812","dateofdeath":"1863","childreninfo":"","family":""}},"children":{"person":[{"name":"Maria","surname":"Gartung","maidenname":"Pushkina","dateofbirth":"1832","dateofdeath":"1919","childreninfo":"","family":""},{"name":"Aleksandr","surname":"Pushkin","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1833","dateofdeath":"1914","childreninfo":"","family":""},{"name":"Grigori","surname":"Pushkin","maidenname":"None","dateofbirth":"1835","dateofdeath":"1905","childreninfo":"","family":""},{"name":"Natalia","surname":"Pushkina","maidenname":"Unknown","dateofbirth":"1836","dateofdeath":"1913","childreninfo":"","family":""}]}}}}}}}}}}}}}
`);

let foundPersonObj = {};
function findPerson(data, name) {
  if (data.name && data.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
    foundPersonObj = data;
  } else {
    if (
      data.marriage &&
      typeof data.marriage.person === "object" &&
      data.marriage.person !== null
    ) {
      findPerson(data.marriage.person, name);
    }
    if (
      data.children &&
      typeof data.children.person === "object" &&
      data.children.person !== null
    ) {
      findPerson(data.children.person, name);
    }
  }
  return foundPersonObj;
}

console.log(findPerson(data.person, "Osip"));
```

Please let me know if you find any issue in this code.